# Crypting and replace

Tags: cryptography

Lets suppose that we have the next string:

*13:45:11:17:-65:107*

This string is a product of RSA crypting. Each number is a byte of a crypted info. 
We crypted it by a public key. After that we decide to "hide" it, the next way:
1=q,3=f,4=d,5=o,7=y,6=p,0=b,-=u,:=t;

and we have the next string, after all:

*qftdotqqtqytupotqby*

Supposing that server side will unhide this string by the reverse way. And decrypt by private key.

So i'm asking: if somebody steal this string, but **he hasn't any access** to our software. He has just a string  - **qftdotqqtqytupotqby**

Is there possibility for him to understand that

**qftdotqqtqytupotqby = 13:45:11:17:-65:107**

Comment: Of course there is. Security by obscurity is never 100%. Read any war history book.

Comment: You seem to be asking: if you do a secret byte-wise ECB of RSA encrypted crypttext, if an attacker can reverse the ECB to gain the crypttext (as they could attack ECB for plaintext by statistical methods)?  Is that the correct question?

Comment: @user1452715 You were not asking about practical methods, you asked "Is there a possibility for him to understand"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the assumption that the attacker cannot access your software and therefore all he has is some ECB (subsitution ciphered) encoded RSA crypttexts, than the answer is no he can't reverse it.  (This assumes the RSA crypttexts are effectively byte-wise "pseudo random" without the secret key.  If they have some plaintext predictable header information than the ECB could be attacked.)

This is however a very weak attacker position to be considering.  In general you should assume an attacker has a copy of your software, otherwise every copy of your software is in effect a secret master key for the whole system.

I would favor using AES with a compiled in secret key to your homebrew ECB.  At least that restricts the secret to the key and not potentially the whole software package.  You could also use this technique to compartmentalize the security risk to just software packages with the same compiled in key.

Comment: AES encrypting RSA ciphertext is pretty silly, all things considered.  the whole reason for using RSA is to protect the data... and if the attacker has access to the system to figure out the substitution cipher (which is what it is -- ECB is an operation mode for ciphers, not an encryption method itself), then the attacker can probably figure out the AES key

Comment: @PeterElliott: The OPs stated question is to protect the RSA ciphertext.  I agree that I don't know why you would want to do that, as it is already encrypted, but that is what he asked.  ECB stands for electronic codebook and is another expression for a substitution cipher - as well as an operation mode for a block cipher (along with CTR, CBC and so on).

Comment: @PeterElliott I agree that it is silly, but I disagree with your reasoning. The simple substitution of the **ASCII representation** of RSA blocks can be broken using trivial statistical methods without access to any of the systems, while that would not be true for the suggested AES «solution».

Comment: @user1131467 I've never heard «ECB» being used as a synonym for «substitution cipher», at least not by experts in the field.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger fair point, it would end up being very insecure, rather than profoundly insecure.  the substitution cipher could be figured out even without access to the software, but either one could be broken with access to source code.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger: The RSA ciphertext is in effect pseudo random, how do you propose to apply a statistical method to it exactly?  And what do you mean by an ASCII representation?  RSA ciphertext is binary, ASCII is a text encoding method.  Read my answer again.

Comment: @PeterElliott:  You're confused I think.  How do you intend to break the substitution cipher of the RSA ciphertext without access to the system?

Comment: @user1131467 Statistical methods.  since the asker has proposed to substitue each number/minus sign/colon with a character, it's pretty easy to figure out what the colon character is.  Then you know that blocks with three characters, the third character is either a minus, 1 or 2.  From there other methods can reveal the rest of the numbers.  While the underlying ciphertext is (sort-of) pseudorandom, the output format is pretty heavily structured.

Comment: @PeterElliott: Ok, but assume he was doing a byte-wise subtitution of the binary RSA crypttext C to some new binary crypttext S.  Then statistical methods could not be applied.  This is how I read his question.

Comment: @user1131467 why would you assume that? there is nothing in the question to suggest that the asker is also doing a byte-wise permutation.  they are asking about a character permutation from the format xx:xx:xx where xx are decimal representations of bytes.

Answer (score 1):

From a strict security perspective, the letter coding is worthless and does not add any protection (see the [Kerkhoff principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle)), since you cannot assume that the attacker does not know your implementation. The security must rest entirely in the key.

Assuming the RSA output really looks exactly as presented in the question (which implies that a ridiculously small RSA keysize was used), then it is easy to at least partly break the simple substitution because the ASCII representation of the RSA ciphertext is highly structured. The most frequent symbol will be the colon (`:`), while the symbol only appearing right next to a colon will be the minus (`-`). If there are four symbols between colons, the leftmost is the minus. If there are three symbols between colons, the leftmost is the minus, the one (`1`) or the two (`2`).  There are 8 digits left which are not as easy, but combined with the small keysize of RSA which is used are no real obstacle.

---

The following is not directly part of the question, but have to be said as well: Whether the RSA part of your protocol is secure depends on so many factors that it is impossible to write a complete answer.  Here just two examples of how the above scheme could be flawed:

- The small block size of one byte implies a keysize of 8 bits, which is ridiculously easy to break even with only pen and paper.
- If that's plain textbook RSA encryption without secure padding (such as PKCS#1 2.x OAEP), the scheme is fatally flawed. The attacker can simply use the public key to compute a dictionary with the encrypted versions of all 256 byte values and use the dictionary to decrypt all your encrypted bytes.

That being said, doing bytewise RSA is horribly inefficient, you are much better off putting all your bytes in a single RSA block, or if you have too much data for a single block, use a hybrid scheme with a symmetrical algorithm for bulk encryption and only RSA encrypt the random session key<del>, as suggested by user1131467</del>.

Comment: I am pretty sure the user1131467 was suggesting that the asker encrypt his RSA ciphertext with AES, not to RSA encrypt an AES key and use AES to encrypt the data.

Comment: @PeterElliott Ah yes, thanks, I have totally misread the answer of user1131467, must have been because the suggested bytewise-RSA-then-AES is such an incredibly unlikely construction from a crypto engineering perspective.

Comment: That is what the OP seemed to ask for.  I have no idea why.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger: The original question is, if you RSA encrypt some plaintext P1, P2 .. Pn into crypttext C1, C2 .. Cn then do a secret byte-wise substitution cipher to make S1, S2 .. Sn - can an attacker recover C1, C2 .. Cn with better than negligble probability given only S1, S2, ... Sn.  The answer is no he can't I think.

Comment: @user1131467 I can see your point about question scoping, I rephrased my answer to make clear what is an answer to the specific question and what is additional brokenness in the scheme which was not part of the question.

Comment: @user1131467 that isn't the question though, its "can an attacker understand qftdotqqtqytupotqby = 13:45:11:17:-65:107".  And an attacker can certainly figure that out, pretty easily at that.